# Create a web page and redirect to it from inside C# side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that receives data from the user (such as his/her name).  The data is submitted using an onclick event with a button.  I want to take this data to the back end (written in C#), and create a thank-you web page.

Then I want to redirect the user to the new thank-you web page using the C# backend.

I don't know how I would create a web page, then send the user to the new thank you page with a redirect.

What is a good way to send information from one aspx page to the other from the C# side?

Comment: Create another page inside visual studio and do the redirect to that page. I don't think there needs to be any dynamic generation.

Comment: How would I change the text in the thank-you page before redirecting to it?  It would vary based on which name is entered.

Comment: Show us the code you have till now.

Comment: Pass the information in the query string of the url or the session.

Comment: Put it in a ViewBag and retrieve it on your page.

Comment: @Romoku:  Please post that as an answer so I credit you.  Also, thank you for helping instead of joining the "narcissistic down-vote bandwagon".

Comment: @Jeevan Jose: Thank you for the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several options in terms of simplicity:

See also: [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

Pass data using the query string

```
var query = string.Format("ThankYou.aspx?email={1}", Server.UrlEncode(email));
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Redirect(query);
```

Pass data using the [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

```
Session["email"] = email;
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");
```

Pass data using a [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)

```
Response.Cookies("email").Value = email;
Response.Cookies("email").Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15);
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");
```

Comment: A quick question, which of these would be the most secure to pass a credit card number?  I was planning to encrypt a credit card number, then decrypt it once it teaches the thank-you page.

Comment: I would probably not pass a CCN directly (for PCI compliance reasons keep that information in your app for a little time as necessary). Your payment processor would most likely have some method to retrieving the information to display back to the user.

Comment: How about passing a "primary key" that uniquely correlates with the encrypted CCN in a SQL database?  Would that be safe to pass?

Comment: Yeah indirection is your friend if you are actually storing a CCN. Something like a transaction number or order receipt number (less information is better). I might go further with a one time id that's only valid for X minutes. Make sure your have proper authorization/authentication setup or you're bound for legal trouble.

Comment: Receipt/transaction number is what I wanted to do originally, but that hasn't been implemented yet.  I'm going to have to work on that then.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you found this answer helpful. I'm not an expert at PCI compliance, but I foresee that being a major pain point in the future.